# How to write Junit for Java Stream

Tags: java, unit-testing, java-8, java-stream

I am recently started using java stream and write a one User service, which returns a stream of users. 
Using that user stream, I process other logic.

Following is the piece of code that I am dealing with stream and it works fine

```
try (Stream<User> users = userService.getStream()) {
    users.forEach(user -> {
    });
```

But when I start writing Junit then it fails with following error message.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.sourceStageSpliterator(AbstractPipeline.java:279)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:647) 
    at com.test.UserService.sendBulkNotification(UserService.java:47)
    at com.test.UserServiceTest.sendNotificationTest(UserServiceTest.java:64)
```

Here is my unit test code:

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
for(long i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setId(i);
    users.add(user);
}

when(userService.getStream()).thenReturn(users.stream());
userService.sendNotification("user", 1, "test.com");
```

Could you please help me to write test case with stream/help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use `thenReturn(users.stream())`, you call the `users.stream()` once and hand that `Stream` object over to the Mockito runtime, which will then return that same instance every time the `when(...)` is triggered.

Since a `Stream` can only be consumed once, any secondary triggers will fail.

You need to give Mockito a factory/supplier object that can produce a new `Stream` every time the trigger fires. Mockito calls that an `Answer`, so call [`thenAnswer(Answer<?> answer)`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.2.4/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html#thenAnswer-org.mockito.stubbing.Answer-) instead.

```
when(userService.getStream()).thenAnswer(invo -> users.stream());
```

You have to name the parameter in the lambda expression, but since you don't use it, you can call it anything. I used `invo` as short for `invocation`, the name of the parameter declared for the [`answer`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.2.4/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html#answer-org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock-) method in the `Answer` functional interface.